# generated URL to make existing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mod-rewrite

I have a problem and I need your help.

I have created a page where after I click a button ,a new URL is generated for this page using AJAX. If I copy the new URL(after generate) and paste it in a new tab of the browser, that browser show notes that **page is not found**. That is normal I know.

Question:

Which way can I choose that new URL can work?

Server-side is PHP.

I add the link with **history.pushState (null, null, hash)**;

Thanks, everybody for help.

Comment: what is the new URL? Share some code for better understanding

Comment: var newURl = "new-url";
 history.pushState (null, null, newURl );

Comment: On first thought this doesn't *look* possible to do at the apache level, but **maybe** with the help of `RewriteMap`. Why generated URLs and not real ones? Are you persisting them anywhere? But if it's possible at all, it'll be much easier to do directly in php.